# Looping through all keys in a tuple of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have created the following dictionaries and a tuple:

```
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
dict2 = {'c':3,'d':4}
dict3 = {'e':5,'f':6}

tuple_purse = dict1, dict2, dict3
```

I want to loop and print out all the keys in all the dictionaries in tuple_purse. I tried the following code:

```
for key in tuple_purse:
    print(key)

for key,value in tuple_purse:
    print(key)
```

And got the following output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
{'c': 3, 'd': 4}
{'e': 5, 'f': 6}
a
c
e
```

Is there a way to loop through all the keys: a,b,c,d,e,f elegantly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple quick double `for` perhaps? Do you need something more?

```
for ddict in tuple_purse:
    for key in ddict:
        print(key)
```

Comment: A dictionary iterates over its keys, so you don't need the explicit `.keys()` call.

Comment: @mwchase An attempt at being as explicit as possible i suppose!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chain` from `itertools`.

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a single sequence

```
import itertools

dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
dict2 = {'c':3,'d':4}
dict3 = {'e':5,'f':6}

tuple_purse = dict1, dict2, dict3

for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(tuple_purse):
    print(x)
```

Comment: You don't actually use the tuple, you would use `chain.from_iterable` on the tuple e.g. `itertools.chain.from_iterable(tuple_purse)`

Comment: @PaulRooney what's wrong with the tuple syntax? I tried it just now in 2.7 and 3.6 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dict1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
dict2 = {'c':3,'d':4}
dict3 = {'e':5,'f':6}
tuple_dict = {**dict1, **dict2, **dict3}
for i in tuple_dict:
    print(i, tuple_dict[i])
```

Note that for the solution above, the code will fail if there are multiple keys of the same name in two or more of the dicts.

Output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
```

Python2 solution

```
new_list = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
for d in new_list:
    for k in d:
        print k, d[k]
```

Output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
```

Comment: Hi, I got a Syntax Error when I run: tuple_dict = {**dict1, **dict2, **dict3} and a TypeError when I run: tuple_dict = {dict1, dict2, dict3}

Comment: @KaneChew that is because you are running the solution in Python2. Try Python3. Either way, I will write a solution for Python2.

Comment: yes, I am running python 2 in a local session of Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @KaneChew Please see my recent. I added a solution for Python2.

Comment: Your solution won't work if any of the dicts have the same key. You should mention that in your answer.

Comment: You wrote "multiple keys of the NAME name". I assume  you meant "SAME name".

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for pointing that out. It is fixed now.